# Comparing large strings in JavaScript with a hash

Tags: javascript, string, hash

I have a form with a textarea that can contain large amounts of content (say, articles for a blog) edited using one of a number of third party rich text editors. I'm trying to implement something like an autosave feature, which should submit the content through ajax if it's changed. However, I have to work around the fact that some of the editors I have as options don't support an "isdirty" flag, or an "onchange" event which I can use to see if the content has changed since the last save.

So, as a workaround, what I'd like to do is keep a copy of the content in a variable (let's call it lastSaveContent), as of the last save, and compare it with the current text when the "autosave" function fires (on a timer) to see if it's different. However, I'm worried about how much memory that could take up with very large documents.

Would it be more efficient to store some sort of hash in the lastSaveContent variable, instead of the entire string, and then compare the hash values? If so, can you recommend a good javascript library/jquery plugin that implements an appropriate hash for this requirement?

Comment: It will probably almost never happen in your use case, but for the casual reader that happens to land here in search for javascript and hashing (like me), it could be worth noting that comparing two hash values is *not* the same as comparing two strings, hash may (and will) collide, that is .. the same hash for two different strings. So in many use cases you should perform a full comparison if you get the same hash value anyway.

Comment: Good point. In addition, in case those readers are wondering, the reason that Hashtable objects, such as those found in many collections APIs, still work despite this is because they contain functionality to handle these collisions when two keys produce the same hash.

Comment: I know this question is 13 years old, but for future readers, memory usage in this case is not a problem to worry about. The longest LotR book is nearly 175,000 words. The average word length in English is around 5 characters, so let's say that's 875,000 characters. At one byte per character that's about 855KB. Lol. Even if you needed 2-byte encoding for every character that's still only ~1.67MB. You could write a book 100 times as long and still not be remotely close to excessive memory usage, even in 2010.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In short, you're better off just storing and comparing the two strings.

---

Computing a proper hash is *not* cheap. For example, check out the [pseudo code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode) or an [actual JavaScript implementation](http://phpjs.org/functions/md5/) for computing the MD5 hash of a string. Furthermore, all *proper* hash implementations will require enumerating the characters of the string anyway.

Furthermore, in the context of modern computing, a string has to be *really*, *really* long before comparing it against another string is slow. What you're doing here is effectively a micro-optimization. Memory won't be an issue, nor will the CPU cycles to compare the two strings.

As with all cases of optimizing: **check** that this is *actually* a problem before you solve it. In a quick test I did, computing and comparing 2 MD5 sums took 382ms. Comparing the two strings directly took 0ms. This was using a string that was 10000 words long. See http://jsfiddle.net/DjM8S.

If you *really* see this as an issue, I would also strongly consider using a poor-mans comparison; and just comparing the length of the 2 strings, to see if they have changed or not, rather than actual string comparisons.

`.`.

Comment: Okay, let's say the user wanted to post a chapter of a novel instead. About how long would the articles have to be to considered the length of a "huge extract of the Bible"?

Comment: MD5'ing the string, then comparing that to the "previous" md5 sum, takes 382ms. Basic string comparison takes 0ms; this is using a string that is ~10000 words long. (http://www.jsfiddle.net/DjM8S/)

Comment: Thank you. This is the better answer of the two, and the sort of answer I was looking for (although the other answer is informative as well). I'd vote for it, but apparently as a new user I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 4):

An MD5 hash is often used to verify the integrity of a file or document; it should work for your purposes.  [Here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-md5.html)'s a good article on generating an MD5 hash in Javascript.

Comment: Useful information, but if I don't need to bother with this, as the other answer suggested, then it's a little less code that I have to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I made a JSperf rev that might be useful here for performance measuring. Please add different revisions and different types of checks to the ones I made!

http://jsperf.com/long-string-comparison/2

I found two major results

- When strings are identical performance is murdered; from ~9000000 ops/s to ~250 ops/sec (chrome)
- The 64bit version of IE9 is **much** slower on my PC, results from the same tests:

  ```
  +------------+------------+
  | IE9 64bit  |  IE9 32bit |
  +------------+------------+
  | 4,270,414  | 8,667,472  |
  | 2,270,234  | 8,682,461  |
  +------------+------------+
  ```

Sadly, jsperf logged both results as simply "IE 9".

Even a precursory look at JS MD5 performance tells me that it is very, very slow (at least for large strings, see http://jsperf.com/md5-shootout/18 - peaks at 70 ops/sec). I would want to go as far as to try AJAXing the hash calculation or the comparison to the backend but I don't have time to test, sorry!